# Why cant bind data from cs to html style attribute?

Tags: c#, html, listview, eval

I created `ListView` and I pass info from cs file to item template.
when I pass information from cs file to item template the CheckBox gets it's value (`rel='<%# Eval("Info") %>`) but the label **doesn't** (`BackColor='<%#Eval("Color")%>'`).
How do I make it work?

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <tr>                            
         <td>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" rel='<%# Eval("Info") %>' runat="server" />
         </td>
         <td>
         <asp:Label ID="colorLbl" runat="server" BackColor='<%#Eval("Color")%>'>&nbsp</asp:Label>
         </td>
       </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: `BackColor` expects a named color. What is the output of `Eval("Color")`?

Comment: well actually its in #ff0044 format..

Comment: That won't work, you could set a CSS style instead: `<asp:Label style='background: <%#Eval("Color")%>;' />`

Comment: I try your example and i get this exception.. '#Eval is not a valid value for the "background" property'.

Comment: The only way it works by using lable and not asp:label..